# How to get list of all dogs based on the person id in Realm

Tags: android, realm

I am using realm in my application and i was trying to find all sorted dogs based on the person id. Here is my Person model.

```
open class Person: RealmObject() {
@Required
@PrimaryKey
var personId : String ?= null

@Required
var dogs : RealmList<Dog> ?= null
 }
```

Below is my dog model

```
open class Dog : RealmObject(){
@Required
@PrimaryKey
var dogId : String ?= null

@Required
var body : String ?= null

@Required
var timeStamp : Any ?= null
}
```

How can i get list of all sorted dogs using the person id. Tell me anybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
open class Dog : RealmObject(){

    @Required
    @PrimaryKey
    var dogId : String ?= null

    @Required
    var body : String ?= null

    @Required
    var timeStamp : Date ?= null

    @field:LinkingObjects("dogs")
    val owners : RealmResults<Person>? = null
}
```

Then

```
import io.realm.kotlin.where

realm.where<Dog>().equalTo("owners.personId", personId).sort("timeStamp").findAllAsync();
```

---

Updating a dog

```
realm.executeTransactionAsync { realm ->
    val dog: Dog? = realm.where<Dog>().equalTo("dogId", dogId).findFirst()
    dog?.apply {
        body = "whatever"
    }
}
```

Comment: will it give all sorted dogs based on person id ? . Also how can i update dog field name "body" based on person id ?

Comment: `realm.executeTransaction { realm -> val dog =... ; dog.body = "doh" `

Answer (score -1):

As you make personId as a primary key so in your realm DB only single list will be there for a particular personId.You can easily get dog list by a simple query.

```
public void getDogs(String personId){
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
try {
    Person person = realm.where(Person.class).equalTo("id", personId).findFirst();
    person.getDogs();
      } finally {
    realm.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: using your code, I'll get sorted list of dogs or unsorted list? .Because i am using timeStamp in my dog model and i wanted to fetch sorted list of dogs based on person Id.

Comment: If this is the only open Realm on the thread, it will throw `IllegalStateException : this Realm instance has been closed, making it unusable`